# Socket.io Emitter.Listener() not working on Android 9 (API level 28)

Tags: android, socket.io

I am trying to connect Node server Socket From android for Live Order track purpose, I couldn't connect to the server in Version 9 Android devices but works fine in lower versions. I didn't get LatLog From Server, but it is fetching in lower Devices.
I am using FCM as well for Notification purposes.

```
 android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

The above Manifest line not worked in my case

Kindly find my code below

```
private void ConnectSocket() {
        try {
            final JSONObject objInit = new JSONObject();
//              objInit.put ("user_joined", bookingKey);
            objInit.put("user_joined", bookingKey);
            if (socket == null) {
                socket = IO.socket(Urls.socketUrl);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Socket is already connected");
            }
            socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    socket.emit("user_joined", bookingKey);
                    locationList.clear();
                }
            }).on("authenticated", new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                }
            }).on("event", new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                }
            }).on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                }
            }).on("newlocation", new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                }
            })
                    .on(bookingKey, new Emitter.Listener() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(Object... args) {
                            final String taxiDetails = args[0].toString();
                            System.out.println("Received from Socket :" + args[0].toString());
                            try {
                                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        try {
                                            JSONObject Job_CarDetails = new JSONObject(taxiDetails);

                                            String latitude = Job_CarDetails.getString("latitude");
                                            String longitude = Job_CarDetails.getString("longitude");

                                            if (locationList.size() == 0) {
                                                MarkerOptions mMarkerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude)))
                                                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_van));
                                                Marker mMarker = googleMap.addMarker(mMarkerOptions);
                                                MarkerList markerList = new MarkerList();

                                                markerList.setLatitude(latitude);
                                                markerList.setLongitude(longitude);
                                                markerList.setMarker(mMarker);
                                                locationList.add(markerList);
                                            } else {
                                                LatLng mToPosition = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude));
                                            }
                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
            if (!socket.connected()) {
                try {
                    socket.connect();
                    socket.emit("user_joined", bookingKey);
                    locationList.clear();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

How can I modify my code, to connect version 9 Devices to the server?? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was not from the Android side, it is on the server-side. This case raised because of local Server pointing when the Server moved to live Server, Socket Connection Worked.
Thanks.